# Pug/Jade mixin with two levels of inner blocks or mixins

Tags: pug, block, mixins

I create a mixing that has multiple blocks and trying to find a workaround to [this Pug issue](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/1693). The aim is to make a mixin where I can add content/variable to default block or not use a block.

As it is now, the content is not added separately to each block but all data is copied into each of the blocks, thus being repeated a few times. I tried to name inner blocks but this way nothing is added.

```
mixin b-block(header, year, cname)
    .div(class='#{year} #{header}__#{year}')
        block b-block
            block header
                .header
                    block
            block year
                .year
                    block
            block content
                .cname
                    block
```

calling it inside a different `.jade` file:

```
include ../b-block

mixin c1()
    div.content
        +b-block('parentclass', '1907', 'm33')
            append header
                |title----header111114
            block year
            append content
                +maincontent('d1')
                h1 image: HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH1_....
```

a version with mixins:

```
mixin b-block(header, year, cname)
    .div(class='#{year} #{header}__#{year}')
        block b-block
            mixin header()
                .header
                    block header
            mixin year()
                .year
                    block year
            mixin content()
                .cname
                    block content
```

calling it inside a different `.jade` file:

```
include ../b-block

mixin c1()
    div.content
        +b-block('parentclass', '1907', 'm33')
            +header()
                |title-----header11111
            +content()
                +maincontent('d1')
                h1 image: HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH1_....
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an unresolved issue with Pug. I don't believe the developers are particularly interested in developing this feature, unfortunately.